# How to find all stabilizater of element of the same orbit.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $\mathfrak S_4\times \mathfrak S_4\longrightarrow \mathfrak S_4$ the action by conjugaison, i.e. $$\sigma \cdot \tau=\sigma \tau\sigma ^{-1}.$$
I have shown that the orbits are
$\mathcal O_{(1234)}$ that contain all $4-$cycle, $\mathcal O_{(123)}$ that contain all $3-$cycle $\mathcal O_{(12)}$ taht contain all transposition, $\mathcal O_{id}$ that only have the identity and $\mathcal O_{(12)(34)}$ that contain $\{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$. I have to compute stabilizer of all elements. I have already $Stab_{(1234)}$. From this, can I deduct the stabilizer of $\mathcal O_{(1234)}$ or I have to compute all of them ? i.e. is there a technic to compute the other stabilizer or not ? (may be using the fact that $\mathfrak S_4/Stab_{(1234)}\cong \mathcal O_{(1234)} $ ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$Use the fact that if $S$ is the stabilizer of $\tau$, then the stabilizer of $\sigma \cdot \tau$ is $\sigma S \sigma^{-1}$.